# Gnome custom hotkey in specific group problem

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, launcher

I am a beginner for Ubuntu. For shortcut/hotkey setting, Ubuntu provide the feature in setting GUI. And I also can add custom hotkey in there.

My question describe blow. Is it possible add custom hotkey in specific "group", like launchers? So I try to search files about this information.

I found the /usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings/01-launchers.xml file. For test it, I comment one KeyListEntry, like email item.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Ik2.png)

Then run dconf update, it work well, the email item is hide. But when I add my new item, t2 item, then run dconf update, the setting GUI will broken after I open it.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Aor.png)

So far, if I still want to add my custom hotkey in specific group, what next should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The settings GUI does not provide facilities to create custom sections for keybindings. You can change/disable predefined shortcuts in the predefined sections, e.g. you can change or disable the "Launch terminal" shortcut in the "Launchers" section. Custom shortcuts are added/removed in the "Custom Shortcuts" section.